# Article V/Fractions

Tags: us-constitution

How can 2/3rds of States call for Convention under Article V when there is no such thing as 1/3 of a State Legislature? 33 Legislatures can apply, or 34, but not the *required* 33.333.  And they didn't write "greater than" or "at least" or "round up or down to nearest whole number".  Legislatures are authoritative and binding only when acting as a body, or whole, or unit.  I assume they meant what they wrote and the simplest construction to their language s/b used.

Comment: They didn't write "greater than or equal to" but that's clearly what they meant.  There's no way they intended that in a US consisting of 15 states it would be impermissible to call a constitutional convention if 11 or more states wanted to.

Comment: Also the discussion of partial legislatures is unnecessary; the constitution doesn't say "two thirds of state legislatures" but "legislatures of two thirds of the several states."

Answer (score 3):

Wherever in the Constitution, a precondition is specified by reference to a fraction of support, it is read as a threshold (your "at least" interpretation). See e.g.:

- the "two-thirds of each House" requirement to remove ineligibility under Sections 3 of the Fourteenth Amendment;
- "the Concurrence of two thirds of the Members present" required to convict after an impeachment trial;
- etc.

This is obviously difficult to find explicit support for, but it is how it has been universally understood to operate.

See e.g. [Oona A. Hathaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oona_A._Hathaway), "[Treaties' End: The Past, Present, and Future of International Lawmaking in the United States](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1108065)" (2008) 117:8 Yale L.J. 1236 at 1309-10. She discusses the "two-thirds majority" requirement imposed by the Treaty Clause ([Article II, Section 2, Clause 2](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artII-S2-C2-1-1/ALDE_00012952/)). In the discussion, she refers to the "sixty-seventh" vote as the tipping point. She refers to the "two-thirds (or sixty-seven votes) requirement of the Treaty Clause."

See also [Adrian Vermeule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian_Vermeule), "[Absolute Voting Rules](https://chicagounbound.uchicago.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1024&context=law_and_economics)" (2005):

> a minimum two thirds supermajority is 67

See also Benjamin Dynkin, "[Shifting from 'Consent' to Advice: Reimagining the Role of the Senate in Foreign Affairs](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2874015)" (2016) 18 Cardozo J. Conflict Resolution 133. He notes that the Constitution provides that presidential vetos can be "overridden by a two-thirds vote of the Congress" (referring to [Article I, Section 7, Clause 2](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S7-C2-2/ALDE_00013645/)). He goes on to say:

> This means that the standard default approval for the
> JCPOA can be overturned only if the Senate is able to muster
> sixty-seven votes against the deal.

Comment: Can you provide a case or statutory citation as to where that interpretation was decided/adopted?

Comment: How could Trump have been impeached? The constitution says that impeachment is valid in cases of high crimes OR misdemeanors, and Trump engaged in high crimes AND misdemeanors.

Comment: The valid legal point is that 2/3 is a not always a whole number, so either the actually-implementable threshold *integer* is achieved by rounding or by truncation. No case law has addressed how the "less than 1" part is disposed of, i.e. does 33 fail to be 2/3 of 50. The question is not about "exactly 2/3", and I don't see any legal support for the implied algorithm for interpreting "at least" when applied to indivisible things.

Comment: @BEWILDERBEAST Article 1 Section 3 also dictates the we choose one third of our Senators every two years. I would be astonished if the issue of how to choose 33.33... Senators was ever brought to a court and would wonder how the attorney bringing the issue would have been admonished.

Comment: @Jen I think Accumulation is expanding the discussion to nit-pic on English grammar. But to pull this into mathematical/logical terms, is High Crimes _or_ Misdemeanors an exclusive (XOR) or inclusive (OR). I highly doubt that most people outside of mathematical logicians or computer professionals take XOR as a default over OR.

Comment: @BEWILDERBEAST it is so obvious as not to need explicit adoption.  The alternative reading, that the fraction must be reached precisely and not exceeded, is absurd, and it is axiomatic that absurd interpretations are invalid.

Comment: @Doneal an OR or XOR in what expression?  Natural-language conjunctions typically do not map well to logical expressions; it depends on how you construct the proposition.  The phrase is in fact "high crimes _and_ misdemeanors," but the whole sentence means that an impeachment may be brought on a charge of treason, a charge of bribery, a charge of any other "high crime," or a charge of any other "high misdemeanor," with the latter meaning crimes or misdeeds of a political nature such as abuse of office.  Implicitly, an impeachment may be brought on multiple charges.

Comment: @user6726 rounding and truncation are not necessary.  The comparison operator `>=` is sufficient.  For example, with 13 states, the threshold is 8 ⅔, with 9 being greater than 8 ⅔ and 8 being less.

Comment: @Acccumulation the constitution actually says "high crimes _and_ misdemeanors," but it doesn't matter. For example, consider "no eating or drinking." This means that you may not eat and you may not drink, neither separately nor at the same time. "Eating and drinking prohibited": arguably ambiguous, but only a smartass would try to argue that the prohibition only applies to doing the activities simultaneously. "Persons caught eating or drinking will be prosecuted": same, but the other way around. Arguing that you were eating _and_ drinking will get you exactly nowhere with the judge.

Comment: @doneal24 the constitution at least explicitly recognizes in the case of senators that the three thirds of the senate may not always be equal in size: "they shall be divided _as equally as may be_ into three Classes." (Emphasis added.)

Comment: Why would it be absurd to posit that the Framer’s intended for a Convention to only be permitted when there are a whole number of State Legislatures?  E.g., two more States would have to be added before amending the original 13’s agreement.  Upon adding the 15th, 18th, 21st, States et cetera those would be years where Convention/amendments are possible.  Is it more absurd than determining representation by counting certain groups of people as 3/5th’s of a person?